# Inserting to sorted node

Tags: java

I'm working on a method which inserts the specified element at the correct position in the sorted list and I can insert the same element several times..however my method didn't insert the element and I couldn't figure out why it doesn't insert all the element in correct position! this is my code

Comment: Please paste your code in correct format with indentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you insert new item only if `current` is null. But when look closer in the above loop, the loop can exit and `current` is not null (first if)

so if `first if` is true the item does not get  into the `linked list`

Answer (score 0):

```
else{    //insert into sorted list
        Node d=new Node(element);
        Node current = head;
        Node pre=null;
        while(current!=null){
            if(c.compare(current.item, element)>0){
                break;
            }
            else{
                pre=current;
                current=current.next;
            }
        }
        if(current == null && pre!=null){    //insert new tail
            pre.next=d;
            tail=d;
            d.pre=pre;
            size++;
            return this; 
        }
        else { //insert when compare is successful and node not at tail. 
            d.pre = pre;
            pre.next = d;
            current.pre = d;
            d.next = current;
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to put the return statement,

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to create a sorted list that can have multiple elements, I'd recommend creating a class

```
public class SortedList<E> extends AbstractSequentialList<E> {

}
```

and implementing the necessary operations. You can look at `Collections.sort()` if you're looking to initially sort the list. Afterward, whenever you insert or remove from the list, you can do a binary search to find the correct location.

Another idea would be to create a class

```
public class Multiplicity<E> {
    private E value;
    private int numberOfDuplicates;
    // etc. etc.
```

then, you could instead just use a `SortedSet<Multiplicity<E>>` and instead of inserting an element that's already there or removing one, instead, you increment or decrement the counter.